# How do I order the answers in rows according to the linked questions in the first row?

Tags: python-2.7

UPDATE: here's my full code. I hope it's enough clear now. I've been thinking on how to solve this for hours. Some options are: matrix, numpy, saving the position for each question. My deepest fear is to rewrite the code just to allow to sort the answers according to the questions.

```
import random as rnd
import csv

list_one=["Question one",
          "Question two"]
list_two=["Question three",
         "Question four",
         "Question five"]
list_three=["Question six",
           "Question seven"]
list_four=["Question eight",
              "Question nine"]
list_five=["Question ten"]

inventory=[listname for listname in dir() if listname.startswith("list_") ]
inventory = [globals()[listname] for listname in inventory]
questions=[]
for lst in inventory:    
    questions+=lst
last_label="user_list"
questions.append(last_label)
iteration=0
answers_file=csv.writer(open('Answers.csv', "wb"),delimiter=',')

all_answers=[]


dim_inv=len(inventory)
while iteration<1000:
    user_list=""
    random_list=rnd.sample(range(dim_inv),dim_inv)
    rnd.shuffle(random_list)


    inventory_position=random_list.pop()
    question_list=inventory[inventory_position]
    dim_question=len(question_list)
    random_question=rnd.sample(range(dim_question),dim_question)
    rnd.shuffle(random_question)
    question_position=random_question.pop()

    list_found=False
    dunno=0
    no=0
    answers=[]
    while list_found==False:
        print  question_list[question_position]+" Y/N/DUNNO"
        answer=str(raw_input())

        #Answer section
        if answer.upper()=="Y":            
            answers.append(answer)
            pick_list=[listname for listname in dir() if listname.startswith("list_") ]
            print "Your list: "+pick_list[inventory_position].replace("list_","")
            list_found=True
        elif answer.upper()=="N":        
            answers.append(answer)
            no+=1
        elif answer.upper()=="DUNNO":        
            answers.append(answer)
            dunno+=1
        else: #12:46 now it changes the question
             while True:
                 try:
                     answer=str(raw_input("Remeber to answer only with Y/N/DUNNO"+"\n"))
                 except ValueError:
                     continue
                 if answer.upper()=="Y" or answer.upper()=="N" or answer.upper()=="DUNNO":
                     if answer.upper()=="Y":            
                        answers.append(answer)
                        pick_list=[listname for listname in dir() if listname.startswith("list_") ]
                        print "Your list: "+pick_list[inventory_position].replace("list_","")
                        list_found=True
                     elif answer.upper()=="N":        
                        answers.append(answer)
                        no+=1
                     elif answer.upper()=="DUNNO":        
                        answers.append(answer)
                        dunno+=1
                     break             

        if no>0 and len(random_list)>0:
           try:
               inventory_position=random_list.pop()  
           except IndexError:
               if len(random_list)==0:
                   print "No more lists from which we can ask questions"
               list_found=True
           question_list=inventory[inventory_position]
           dim_question=len(question_list)
           random_question=rnd.sample(range(dim_question),dim_question)
           rnd.shuffle(random_question)
           try:
               question_position=random_question.pop()
           except IndexError:
               print "No more questions for the list"
               list_found=True
           dunno=0 
           no=0 

        elif len(random_list)==0 and len(random_question)==0:
            print "No more lists from which we can ask questions",
            list_found=True

        elif dunno>0 and dunno<dim_question:  
            try:
               question_position=random_question.pop()
               dim_question=len(question_list)#experimental
            except IndexError:
               print "No more questions for the list"
               list_found=True      


        elif dunno==dim_question: 
           try:
               inventory_position=random_list.pop()  
           except IndexError:
               print "No more lists from which we can ask questions"
               list_found=True
           question_list=inventory[inventory_position]
           dim_question=len(question_list)
           random_question=rnd.sample(range(dim_question),dim_question)
           rnd.shuffle(random_question)
           try:
               question_position=random_question.pop()           
           except IndexError:
               print "No more questions for the list"
               list_found=True
           dunno=0
           no=0
    answers= answers + ['']*(len(questions)-len(answers))
    answers.append(user_list)       
    answers_file.writerows([answers])
    iteration+=1
    all_answers.append(answers)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: It's a good idea to post a minimal reproducible example, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve with a subset of your data

Comment: the code is long. I don't want you to use time understand it all. I'll find a way to make the question more understandable

Comment: I updated the details. Want more?

Comment: I clarified the question. I'm ashamed of the mistake I did in the title

Comment: Updated again. I hope it's the last

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
from random import shuffle

lines = [] #your list
linesShuffled = [] 

for i in lines:
    q = i[0]
    a = shuffle(i[1:])
    a.insert(0,q)
    linesShuffled.append(a)
```

You take each line of your data, assuming you have a list with several string lists inside. You take out the first element and randomize the rest. Then merge again in a new list.

**Edit:**

In case of you have a list per cycle, is easier. You should do something like this in each cycle:

```
from random import shuffle

line = [] #your line
lineShuffled = [] 

q = line[0]
lineShuffled = shuffle(line[1:])
lineShuffled.insert(0,q)
```

Comment: I have a list for every cycle. Are you suggesting to merging the list at every cycle in a list of lists?

Comment: with line you meant the list of questions or the list of answers?

Comment: I suppose you meant questions with q

Comment: and what assures me that the result of shuffled will put the answers in the position of the question? I can see this because, according to the answers, I have a label that "summarize" them

Comment: I'm thinking about putting the answers in a dictionary, where the key is the position of the question and the value is the answer.